# How can abstract my code to avoid duplication if a increase the number of variables to consider?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Currently there are be 4 combinations

- Add hours.
- Add days.
- Subtract hours.
- Subtract days.

```
private String modifyDate(Character symbol, LocalDateTime date, Long digits, String period) {
        switch (symbol) {
            case '+':
                if (period.contains("days")) {
                    return date.plusDays(digits).toString();
                } else {
                    return date.plusHours(digits).toString();
                }
            case '-':
                if (period.contains("days")) {
                    return date.minusDays(digits).toString();
                } else {
                    return date.minusHours(digits).toString();
                }
            default:
                System.out.println("Not defined operation");
        }

        return "";
    }
```

If a new *period* is added (let's say *years*), it will be necessary to add a new if statement in each case:

```
if (period.contains("years")) {
    return date.plusYears(digits).toString();
} else if (period.contains("days")) {
    return date.plusDays(digits).toString();
} else {
    return date.plusHours(digits).toString();
}
```

Also if a new unexpected case is added (a combination, especial cases), then it will be necessary to repeat the logic to validate the periods.

Do you have a recommendation to improve the solution? Pattern recommendation, functional interfaces implementation, any recommendation is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Comment: Hello @JaredSmith, I appreciate the time to review my question.
Part of my initial solution was creating a *Functional interface* with single method *operation*, then implement different cases that I have; addDays, addHours, subtractDays, subtractHours.
From there, pass the implementation depending on the case, faced some blockers and it was the moment to evaluate different paths (ask the question) and search for recommendations:

private InterfaceName addDays = (LocalDate date, Long period)
            -> date.plusDays(period)

Comment: Functional programming is about composing referentially transparent functions, using higher-order functions, avoiding side-effects, and working with immutable data. So I'll ask again, what about that method is functional in that sense? Please understand, when you tag a question with a tag, people who subscribe to that tag get your question in their feed, and if your question doesn't match the tag it can be ill-received.

Answer (score 1):

The general recommendation by Martin Fowler is to Replace Conditional with Polymorphism.

https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

In terms of design patterns, this would often be the Strategy Pattern Replace Conditional Logic with Strategy.

https://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionalWithStrategy.html

If you have a small, finite set of conditions, I recommend using an enum to implement the Strategy Pattern (provide an abstract method in the enum and override it for each constant).

I hope it might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Muhammad, recommendation is really cool and the detailed suggestions, I will review it deeply and come back with the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is solvable through a Strategy Pattern in combination with an Enum.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Comment: I really appreciate the time to review my question and add the suggestion, I will review the pattern, try to implement it and share my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Great recommendations mentioned in previous comments, I would add just a few details:

1. Continue searching about "replace conditionals with patterns", [here is a different example](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/replace-conditional-logic-with-strategy-pattern.html).

- Strategy implementation using enums

```
public enum Strategy {
    ADD {
        @Override
        public String methodImp(String daysHours, LocalDateTime date, Long plusPeriod) {
            return period.contains(Enum1.DAYS.label)
                    ? date.plusDays(plusPeriod).toString() :
                    date.plusHours(plusPeriod).toString();
        }
    },
    SUBTRACT {
        @Override
        public String methodImp(String daysHours, LocalDateTime date, Long minusPeriod) {
            return period.contains(Enum1.DAYS.label)
                    ? date.minusDays(minusPeriod).toString() :
                    date.minusHours(minusPeriod).toString();
        }
    };

    public abstract String methodImp(String daysHours, LocalDateTime date, Long timePeriod);
}
```

2. You could implement 2 enums:

- One to contain the days/hours

```
public enum Enum1 {
    DAYS("days"),
    HOURS("hours");

    public final String label;

    private Period(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

- One for math operators, if you are going to receive a character, then I recommend searching by *label*, the implementation below.

```
public enum MathOperators {
    PLUS('+'),
    SUBTRACT('-');

    private static final Map<Character, Operator> BY_LABEL = new HashMap<>();
    public final Character label;

    static {
        for (Operator e: values()) {
            BY_LABEL.put(e.label, e);
        }
    }

    Operator(Character label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public static Operator valueOfLabel(Character label) {
        return BY_LABEL.get(label);
    }
}
```

3. Finally the context logic:

```
public static String contextLogic(Character mathOperator, String daysHours, LocalDateTime date, Long timePeriod) {
        var value = "";
        switch (Operator.valueOfLabel(operator)) {
            case PLUS:
                value = Strategy.ADD.operation(daysHours, date, timePeriod);
                break;
            case SUBTRACT:
                value = Strategy.SUBTRACT.operation(daysHours, date, timePeriod);
                break;
        }

        return value;
    }
```